# minimum number of variables required for proc transpose

Tags: sas

Is there any restriction on minimum number of variables in proc transpose?
i have data as below.

```
group subgroups
A        1
A        2
A        3
B        1
B        2
```

i need to transpose data and desired out put is

```
A  B
1 1
2 2
3 .
```

Please help me out with your suggestion.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 2):

Transpose twice to get what you want;

```
data have;
    input group $ subgroups;
    cards;
    A        1
    A        2
    A        3
    B        1
    B        2
    ;
    proc transpose data=have out=temp;
    by group;
    run;

    proc transpose data=temp out=want(drop=_name_);
    id group;
    run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does the first row in the output have A=1 and B=1?  Why is the missing value for B in the last observation?  Do you want to preserve the original order?  If so then make an order variable and use that as a by variable in the transpose.

```
data middle ; 
  set have ;
  by group ;
  if first.group then row=0;
  row+1; 
run;
proc sort data=middle ; 
  by row group; 
run;
proc transpose data=middle out=want ;
  by row;
  id group;
  var subgroups;
run;
```